# Get already made instance and call method

Tags: objective-c

I have classes such as

in my MainScene.m class

```
@implementation MainScene{
    Child *_child;
} 

- (void)myMethod:(int)num{
```

MainScene Class made at the beginning of appication, then which has pointer for the childclass.

I can call childclass method easily like [_child myChildMethod] though,

I would like to call myMethod from childClass.

How can I get the instance of parentclass already revoked?
How can I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the child class can add an instance variable of MainScene, or you can create a delegate, although adding an instance variable to child and then setting it to self seems like a slightly easier design.

Comment: Thanks I can slove the problem as you taught me. I make an instance variable of MainScene.